# ¿Cómo acceder a una variable privada en TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Se que esta pregunta parece taboo y va en contra del enfoque de la POO, pero tengo el siguiente inconveniente, necesito acceder a un atributo de un componente especifico de una la librería específicamente [Md2/Autocomplete](https://github.com/Promact/md2/tree/master/src/lib/autocomplete) quiero acceder al valor del campo de búsqueda `_inputValue` y no solo tener el valor del resultado, pero resulta que el atributo es privado y bueno no quiero copiar todo el modulo y modificarlo solo por acceder a dicho valor.

El siguiente codigo no funciona

HTML

```
<md2-autocomplete #autocomplete></md2-autocomplete>
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('autocomplete', undefined) autocomplete: Md2AutoComplete;

// al ser un atributo privado la siguiente llamada no devuelve nada
console.log(this.autocomplete._inputValue)
```

Aclaro que intente usar el evento de salida `textChange()` pero me devuelve el texto actual menos el ultimo carácter presionado por lo que no me sirve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo estás haciendo mal a la hora de acceder a ese atributo:

Los modificadores de alcance de TypeScript (private/public/protected) sólo tienen sentido en tiempo de compilación para evitar malas prácticas (como las que estás haciendo), pero puesto que Javascript no tiene esa funcionalidad, sencillamente no se aplica en tiempo de ejecución:

De la [especificación oficial de Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1.6):

> Accessibility is a design-time construct; **it is enforced during static type checking but does not
>   imply any runtime enforcement**.

Traducción:

La accesibilidad es una creación en el momento del diseño; **se hace cumplir en tiempo de comprobación estática de tipos pero no implica ninguna imposición en tiempo de ejecución**.

Por ejemplo, este código:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {
    }

    public shout(phrase: string) {
        alert(phrase);
    }

    private whisper(phrase: string) {
        console.log(phrase);
    }
}
```

genera este otro en Javascript:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    Person.prototype.shout = function (phrase) {
        alert(phrase);
    };
    Person.prototype.whisper = function (phrase) {
        console.log(phrase);
    };
    return Person;
})();
```